# Gradle, put .png and .property files into fat jar

Tags: gradle

I want to get my .property and .png files in my fat jar so that the externalised strings work.

build.gradle thing:

```
...
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes("Manifest-Vesrion": "1.0",
                "Implementation-Title": "Gradle",
                "Implementation-Version": archiveVersion,
                "Build-Prefix": "beta",
                "Build-Version": "1.0",
                "Build-Suffix": "release",
                "Created-By": "Danny Piper (djpiper28 on github)",
                "Main-Class": "dannypiper.mazegenerator.Main")
    }

    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect() { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

INCLUDE!!

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes("Manifest-Vesrion": "1.0",
                "Implementation-Title": "Gradle",
                "Implementation-Version": archiveVersion,
                "Build-Prefix": "beta",
                "Build-Version": "1.0",
                "Build-Suffix": "release",
                "Created-By": "Danny Piper (djpiper28 on github)",
                "Main-Class": "dannypiper.mazegenerator.Main")
    }

    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect() { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }

    from('src/main/java') {
        include 'dannypiper/mazegenerator/*.png'
        include 'dannypiper/mazegenerator/*.properties'
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you could have put them in `src/main/resources`.